# How to broadcast large variable to local disk of each node in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, broadcast

As i know, broadcast is useful to get local copy of a variable. And the size of the variable must fit in worker's memory.

In my case, However, I want to get local copy of **large variable** which is not fit in worker's memory.

How can i broadcast this large variable not using broadcast function in Spark?

Comment: What kind of variable is that? What kind of operations will you perform with the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question :

> In my case, However, I want to get local copy of large variable which
>   is not fit in worker's memory.
>
> How can i broadcast this large variable not using broadcast function
>   in Spark?

AFAIK this is not possible (which wont fit in to workers memory...)
either by `sc.broadcast(..)` or `functions.broadcast(hint)`

please be aware that there is a memory limit of 2GB(TorrentBroadcast ) see [SPARK-6235 - Address various 2G limits](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235)

you can ingest that data (which you want to broadcast) in to hadoop/hbase(or any no sql)  or may be memcached and then you can look up.

- Have a look at [Load spark data into Mongo / Memcached for use by a Webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459659/load-spark-data-into-mongo-memcached-for-use-by-a-webservice)

Answer (score 1):

> **large variable** which is not fit in worker's memory

Like Ram mentioned above, if it doesn't fit in worker's memory, there is no way you can use it, **even if you can broadcast it**.

If you're trying to do lookup with large dataset, you can make a connection pool to a database at each worker node. If you have a model, you can save the model to each worker node and do a file read during `foreachPartition`. Depending on your use case, there maybe other solutions.